# Import .pem public and private keys to JKS keystore

Tags: cryptography, certificate, public-key, keystore, private-key

I have public and private keys in separate .pem files that I would need to get into a JKS keystore somehow.

Tried using the -import command in KeyTool for this, which gives an "not an X.509 certificate" error.

I'm guessing the solution has to do with OpenSSL, but I'm not entirely sure what to do with it.

Would really appreciate any help with this, since I'm completely clueless with everything crypto-related.

Thanks in advance,
--Rolf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KeyTool expects the objects in DER format. PEM is Base64-encoded DER, with a header and a footer. KeyTool cannot parse PEM.

However, OpenSSL can convert PEM objects to DER. E.g., for an X.509 certificate, the `-outform DER` command-line flag instructs OpenSSL to use DER as its output format.

[This page](http://conshell.net/wiki/index.php/OpenSSL_to_Keytool_Conversion_tips) apparently contains some more detailed explanations.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering!

I managed to convert the private key to DER with OpenSSL, but not the public key.

openssl x509 -in pubkey.pem -inform PEM -out pubkey.der -outform DER
results in the following error:

unable to load certificate
5280:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:.\crypto\pem\pem_lib
.c:642:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE

I'm guessing that it expects the public key file to begin with a "BEGIN TRUSTED CERTIFICATE" header, but what it actually contains is "BEGIN PUBLIC KEY"

Comment: You have a "lone public key". You need a certificate. KeyTool follows the KeyStore format, which accepts private keys only if they come with certificates. A certificate contains the public key, along with other information such as an identity (the "key owner name") and a signature by a "certificate authority". You could use the private key to create a "self-signed certificate" (a certificate where the signature is computed relatively to the key itself); try this: `openssl req -new -x509 -key privkey.pem -out cert.pem`

Comment: How did you solve the "Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE" error ? thanks